# WPF - Binding a user control's code behind property to another property in the father's code behind

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding, code-behind

I'm trying to bind a user control's code behind property to a property in another component's code behind that's "higher" up in the xaml hierarchy.

I have my main window which has an IEventAggregator property in its code behind. The main window contains a few user controls and I'm trying to access that property from one of the user controls' code behind.

My xaml hierarchy: main window -> some display control -> another display control with tabs that each has a user control in it -> the wanted control.

I'm trying to do this because at the current situation, each tab item has a user control inside it and each user control's constructor takes some time to run and it delays my application. I want the user control's constructor to run only when the specific tab item is clicked so I removed the user control from the xaml code and handled the tab item click event and just changed the content property of it from the code behind. The only thing I need to do now is to give this control a property that it was getting by {Binding} from the code behind instead.

I hope my question is clear enough.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to go up the visual tree, find the parent control and get the property from there.

**Updated #1**

**In your user control**

```
...
            var foundControl = this;
            while (true)
            {
                //get parent item
                foundControl = foundControl.FindParent<Control>();
                if (foundControl == null) break;
                if (foundControl is IHaveSpecificProperty)
                    break;
            }
            var haveSpecificProperty = foundControl as IHaveSpecificProperty;
            if (haveSpecificProperty == null) return;
            var specificProperty = haveSpecificProperty.SpecificProperty;
            //add your logic here
...
```

**Common interface code:**

```
//should be in a common place and both the ParentControl and the ChildControl should have an access to it,
//in addition your ParentControl should implement this interface
public interface IHaveSpecificProperty
{
    object SpecificProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Helper class code:**

```
public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static T FindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //get parent item
            DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

            //we've reached the end of the tree
            if (parentObject == null) return null;

            //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            child = parentObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards.

Comment: OK that really helped me and I managed to get to the main window but I still have a small issue. The main window is part of a "main" project that starts my application while all my other windows and controls are in a "presentation" project and it's kinda wrong for the presentation project to know the main one so I can't convert the main window from a dependency object to the actual main window class which means I can't access the specific property on the main window. Any ideas?

Comment: @DannyIdlis Do you have some common project like infra that both the "main" and the "presentation" having the access to it?

Comment: I'm getting an error with my interface: Assembly generation failed -  referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Composite' does not have a strong name. I tried everything suggested in stack overflow but no success, I can't compile. :(

Comment: @DannyIdlis what is the problem? what did you do?